# Problem with MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

This time my setup looks like this: one table with galleries names

```
CREATE TABLE GalleriesName (
    gallery_id
    , gallery_name
)
```

and another table with galleries photos

```
CREATE TABLE GalleriesPhotos (
    photo_id
    , photo_gallery_id
    , photo_name
)
```

What I need is to get all the galleries with one random picture for each gallery.

Is it possible to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with a single query?

Yes it possible. you need to learn to make SUBSELECTS with mysql. Just select a gallery then subselect a random image [ with rand() ]  with that gallery ID =)

http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Subselect/

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you have setup your tables in terms of relationship of primary key and foreign key. As for random rows, you need to append `order by rand()` to your query.